# Kernal Error on Jupyter Notebook. how to fix this?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I tried installing google-colab and now jupyter notebook won't work, neither will anaconda navigator. Only way I can open jupyter notebook is via cmd but then the kernal error I get means I can't run anything

Here is the error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1512, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 70, in post
    model = yield gen.maybe_future(
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 91, in start_kernel_for_session
    kernel_id = yield gen.maybe_future(
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 307, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 141, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 185, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 309, in start_kernel
    kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 256, in pre_start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 468, in write_connection_file
    self.connection_file, cfg = write_connection_file(self.connection_file,
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 138, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 461, in secure_write
    win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
  File "c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 387, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Run Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install in an Admin command prompt

ref: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1431